# How to get KWin-like window snapping in Xfce?

Tags: linux, kde, xfce, window-manager, kwin

There's a feature in KWin I love: when you drag the edge of one window to the edge of another, KWin will "snap" them together, locking them edge to edge, perfectly.

There are several reasons why I'd prefer not to use KWin, so how can I get this feature in other window managers, such as Xfce (what I'm currently using)? Are there other window managers that have this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the GUI menu, `Settings manager` -> `Window Manager` and at the `Advanced` tab, you will have the option to check `Windows snapping` -> `to other windows` together with a bar to adjust the snapping.

For xfce4 4.12

[image]

Comment: You must also *uncheck* the "With a dragged window" box half-way down. That is critical!